# Can not put anything into /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/

Tags: java, jsp, ubuntu, webserver, tomcat7

I was starting on JAVA web development today and encountered some problems, I installed my tomcat7 on my ubuntu machine. Now when I browse to //localhost:8080, I get the default welcome page saying:

This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at: `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html`

Tomcat7 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system instance of Tomcat is installed with `CATALINA_HOME` in `/usr/share/tomcat7` and `CATALINA_BASE` in `/var/lib/tomcat7`, following the rules from `/usr/share/doc/tomcat7-common/RUNNING.txt.gz`.

But strangely when I try `echo $CATALINA_HOME` nothing shows up. 
Also I can not copy/create anything in the default /var/lib/tomcat7/ROOT though it's just a matter of providing few permissions but I was wondering whether it is the right way to do it?,

What I would like to do is create a separate directory in my home where I can put my web application and tomcat can read hem from there. Is there a way to do it? In apache I can do it by changing the document-root and directory but I don't know how to do it for tomcat

Comment: Have you check your `.bashrc` if `CATALINA_HOME` is defined?

Comment: If you installed tomcat using `apt-get`, you might consider removing it and [using the standalone version of tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567597/tomcat-on-linux-centos-incorrect-java-version/1568390#1568390), which you could extract into your $HOME directory or somewhere else convenient.

Comment: Why do you want to copy anything to the ROOT folder? to deploy an application just copy it to the webapps folder, or use Tomcat manager.

Comment: @RobHruska: I don't want to do it , as it would mess up my eclipse configurations (which is alreazdy kind of messed up)..is there no other way?

Comment: Linux distros have a long track record of goofing up things like Tomcat. In any case, I see no programming question here, try serverfault?

Comment: There's nothing messed with with packaged Tomcat installations, it's just that most people only know one way of configuring a Tomcat deployment (unzip and run), and any other way is considered foreign and not-understandable.  Packaged versions typically have the sub-directories in the "unzip and run" method implemented as symlinks to the real directories, and have "read the /etc" config files scripts embedded in the previously `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin` programs, which are relocated to `/usr/bin`.  Beyond a few logging changes, it's really all the same.

Comment: may be that's because most of the people running into these issues are newbies trying to run their first webapp, and so do not want to mess it up?

Answer (score 11):

> But strangely when I try echo $CATALINA_HOME nothing shows up.

This is because the packaged version sets `CATALINA_HOME` just prior to launching Tomcat, after reading it from a configuration file (typically somewhere in /etc).

> Also I can not copy/create anything in the default
>   /var/lib/tomcat7/ROOT though it's just a matter of providing few
>   permissions but I was wondering whether it is the right way to do it?

The permissions problem has to do with you not being root (or the Tomcat user).  Most packaged Tomcat installations (deb or RPM) tend to install with a specific user in mind, and copying stuff in as a different sometimes won't work.

`/usr/share/tomcat7` is your `CATALINA_HOME` directory, and it has links to the other directories, such as `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`, `/etc/tomcat7`, etc.  You shouldn't copy directly into a web application, you should package the web application into a WAR file and "deploy" it.  The advantages are numerous.

> What I would like to do is create a separate directory in my home
>   where I can put my web application and tomcat can read hem from there.
>   Is there a way to do it?

Yes, one is created when "deploying a web app".  Look to the standard Tomcat7 documentation, and consider installing the "manager" web application if you like a non-command line interface.  Now that you know what "installation" of a web app is called, it will likely be an easier task.

> In apache I can do it by changing the document-root and directory but
>   I don't know how to do it for tomcat

Tomcat has a different, slightly more restrictive set of requirements for a document-root.  You need to learn it, and just come to terms with the idea that it's never going to be the same.  Basically under the "webapps" directory, is a WAR file or a expanded directory that came from a WAR file.  Editing in-place is not a good idea for Tomcat, as the CGI-equivalents are not read from disk each time they are ran, they are linked into the memory of Tomcat.  This means that a change in the directory might not affect your web application, which is good enough reason to not bother changing the on-disk files for a deployed web application.

Modify the web application, repackage it, and update the deployment.  It's really the "right" way to go with Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the details..meanwhile I removed tomcat, downloaded a tar and unziped into my home folder, after adding few symbolic links I am able to patch it up even with eclipse also... it runs perfectly fine from there (At least till now)....Do you think I might run into some issues later?...or why this is not the right way to do it?

Comment: The kinds of issues you will run into will be the kinds of issues that concern IT administration, not the kinds of issues that concern developers.  Basically, logging isn't integrated with the rest of the OS, startup / shutdown isn't integrated with the OS, configuration files are not where the OS stores config files, binaries are not default-reachable by the OS, there is no dedicated user to limit OS scope, libraries are not integrated with OS libraries, and the temporary space is not inside the temporary space reserved by the OS. Your setup is fine for development, just don't deploy that way

Answer (score 4):

Give permission 777 to the webroot folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 Webroot
```

After moving to the tomcat folder

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`